# Amazon LEX Android : BadRequestException

Tags: android, amazon-cognito, amazon-lex

I trying to integrate Amazon Lex in android App. I followed https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/LexSample and performed all steps but ends up with below error.

> 08-10 11:08:08.013 30552-30707/com.amazonaws.sample.lex D/AWSMobileClient: waitForSignIn: userState:GUEST
> 08-10 11:08:12.286 30552-30552/com.amazonaws.sample.lex D/TextActivity: Error: Invalid Bot Status: Bot ScheduleAppointment_dev has status FAILED (Service: AmazonLexRuntime; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 37879694-02e8-49bb-9601-901f85da30ef)
> 08-10 11:08:12.287 30552-30552/com.amazonaws.sample.lex E/TextActivity: Interaction error
> com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.model.BadRequestException: Invalid Bot Status: Bot ScheduleAppointment_dev has status FAILED (Service: AmazonLexRuntime; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 37879694-02e8-49bb-9601-901f85da30ef)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:730)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
> at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.AmazonLexRuntimeClient.invoke(AmazonLexRuntimeClient.java:884)
> at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.AmazonLexRuntimeClient.postContent(AmazonLexRuntimeClient.java:622)
> at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.InteractionClient$3.run(InteractionClient.java:452)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Can anyone please help me out with these.

Comment: Since it is a BadRequest error, you should dig around and find the exact request that is being sent to Lex. Check your AWS CloudWatch logs. We'll need more information to help you.

Comment: At AWS CloudWatch logs nothing is getting recorded other lex sample and chatbot creation log steps done following link : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/LexSample

Comment: @DurgeshShankar how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your AWS console and then search for Amazon Lex. Make sure the botname you reference is there and that you publish it as well.